# How do I associate a green cross add document icon with an InfoPath template

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, hyperlink

I have the below URL for a InfoPath template which is great as it gets the user directly into the template.  I know in SP 2013 I can use a Promoted Link to better visualize the link, but what about SP 2010 ?

At minimum I would like to associate an icon (maybe the green cross add icon if it is available for download) with the URL.

http://teamsite/_layouts/FormServer.aspx?XsnLocation=http://teamsite/ContosoResourcePlanning/Forms/template.xsn&OpenIn=browser&SaveLocation=http://teamsite/ContosoResourcePlanning&Source=http://teamsite/ContosoResourcePlanning/Forms/AllItems.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a content editor web part or on a wiki page you'd enter something like:

```
<a href="http://teamsite/_layouts/FormServer.aspx?XsnLocation=http://teamsite/ContosoResourcePlanning/Forms/template.xsn&OpenIn=browser&SaveLocation=http://teamsite/ContosoResourcePlanning&Source=http://teamsite/ContosoResourcePlanning/Forms/AllItems.aspx" title="Click to submit a new item">
 <img src="http://contoso.com/image.jpg" alt="New item image" title="Click to submit a new item"/>
 New Form</a>
```